# Anybody did a Migration from BitBucket hosted Git LFS server to Artifactory Git Large File Storage server

Tags: artifactory, git-lfs

I want to know the steps you followed to migrate a BitBucket hosted GIT LFS server to Artifactory Git LFS server. I tried to follow Git hub procedure but having doubts

https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.19/admin/installation/migrating-to-a-different-git-large-file-storage-server